# jwt lexik JWT Authetication not found

Tags: symfony, authentication, jwt, symfony4, api-platform.com

I have been looking for a solution for a while now.
All authentication system is in place, I get my token but when I use it to retrieve the data I get a 404 jwt not found.

I have an emergency on this project, a help will help me a lot.

this is my security.yaml:

```
app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern: ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        json_login:
            check_path: /api/login_check # or api_login_check as defined in config/routes.yaml
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
    

    main:
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Pour la declaration du controller:

```
api_login_check:
  path: /api/login_check
```

Comment: I don't understand anything, I have followed the documentation as it should be followed at I have looked at this doc (https://techjourney.net/how-to-decrypt-an-enrypted-ssl-rsa-private-key-pem-key/). But I still don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the following;
go to /config/packages/lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'

    token_extractors:
        authorization_header:
                        enabled: true
                        prefix:  Bearer
                        name:    Authorization
        cookie: // if you are using cookie
                enabled: true
                name: cookie_name // set the cookie name
```

If you are using httpClient; then you can Authorization: 'Bearer ' .$token in your header as follows;

```
 $headers = [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ];
```

NOTE:  make sure you have jwt directory, where you have private and public keys.